# how can i have a navigation page on a website if i do not know the site name such as www.randomsite.com

Tags: php

This is part of my navigation page but it sends me to mysite.com/mysite.com/myfolder.php

```
<a href ="<?php echo "http://".$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']."/myfolder.php"; ?>">home</a>
```

Problem #1: sometimes `$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']` prints mysite.com and sometimes it prints www.mysite.com. im not sure if this could be a problem or not but i want it to always print the same thing so i dont run into strange problems in the future.

Problem #2: I will not know the website name so i need to be sure when they add this file that the home button on the navigation will send them to theirsite.com/myfolder/index

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use relative URLs.  Instead of making the link point to http://mysite.com/myfolder.php or http://www.mysite.com/myfolder.php, make the link point to /myfolder.php.  The browser knows that the host is www.mysite.com and that the protocol is HTTP, so the browser prepends the http://www.mysite.com part.

As an example, fire up your browser's developer tools and inspect the StackOverflow logo at the top of this page.  You'll see that the markup is

```
<a href="/">Stack Overflow</a>
```

Comment: I thought that there were situations where a relative root wasn't satisfactory in PHP. I thought there were some occasions where a direct path was required.

Comment: The browser doesn't care about how the page was generated, so PHP/non-PHP isn't an issue.  But in general, the rule is simple: as long as the target page of a link matches the current page's hostname and protocol, relative URLs are just fine.  If you want your link to point to another site, or to a different subdomain, or to an FTP implementation on your host, *then* you need an absolute URL.  Otherwise, a relative URL is just the same as an absolute URL.

Answer (score 3):

Use URLs *relative to the root*, not complete URLs:

```
<a href ="/myfolder.php">home</a>
```

Takes you to `/myfolder.php`, regardless of the domain name it's running on.

The www vs. no-www should be handled by redirecting *any* address starting with www to its non-www counterpart, or vice-versa. That's a simple configuration of the individual web server, for example using an .htaccess directive.